# My iPad does not work when it's camera time!

Tags: ipad

It doesn't let me take pictures or take videos any more on my camera!
It says storage is full?

Comment: I'm locking it as it is an example off-topic question. See [Why we're not customer support for company X or product Y](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y)